# Why my code is compiled correctly even when I use partially compiled libraries

Tags: angular, angular12

I am using angular application version `12.2.16`.
I am using this third party dependency
https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/src/ng-select/tsconfig.lib.json
It's comilationMode is set to true.

If I follow the documentation in Angular

https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#consuming-partial-ivy-code-outside-the-angular-cli

they state that we should use webpack and babel loader to consume third party dependepdency which has `partial-ivy` code.

But when I build my application with the default builder `"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",`

I do not have problems consumig this library.Are there some changes in this ?
Why is this happening ? Is their documentation out of the date or I am missing something ?
From angular 12+ we can consume any library now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `@angular/cli` to build your application, transpiling of  external non-ivy dependencies is automatically taken care of.

Comment: @Ganev tnx for your response. In what situations this is not taken care of ?I don't know because this is not mentioned on angular documentation

Comment: You are running an Angular project without it's official CLI tool - you have your own webpack config (started from scratch).

Comment: Okay thank you when there are that cases which makes problems